# Не работает cheked

Tags: jquery

Всем привет!

Есть вот такой URL http://kn-peterburg.ru/search/?submit_short=&srch_totarea_for=3000&ym_island=c58de48c-11dc-4848-80d8-843e3b5fe9e0&srch_optype=3&srch_price_from=0&srch_subtype=44&srch_totarea_from=1&ym_reqid=&srch_adm2[]=2&action=search&srch_price_for=1000000000

где srch_optype=3 и srch_subtype=44, нужно, чтобы при таком урл именно данные поля были cheked (и для других варицаий).

Пока додумал до:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        switch(jQuery('#srch_optype').val()){
        case '1':
        jQuery('#chfield').html('<label class="label3">Количество комнат:</label><div class="spadc"><input class="new1" type="checkbox" name="srch_roomqty[]" value="1" id="check1" /> <label for="check1" class="label4">1</label><input class="new1" type="checkbox" name="srch_roomqty[]" value="2" id="check2" /> <label for="check2" class="label4">2</label><input class="new1" type="checkbox" name="srch_roomqty[]" value="3" id="check3" /> <label for="check3" class="label4">3</label><input class="new1" type="checkbox" name="srch_roomqty[]" value="4" id="check4" /> <label for="check4">4 и более</label></div>');
        break;
        case '2':
        jQuery('#chfield').html('<label class="label3">Количество комнат:</label><div class="spadc"><input class="new1" type="checkbox" name="srch_roomqty[]" value="1" id="check1" /> <label for="check1" class="label4">1</label><input class="new1" type="checkbox" name="srch_roomqty[]" value="2" id="check2" /> <label for="check2" class="label4">2</label><input class="new1" type="checkbox" name="srch_roomqty[]" value="3" id="check3" /> <label for="check3" class="label4">3</label><input class="new1" type="checkbox" name="srch_roomqty[]" value="4" id="check4" /> <label for="check4">4 и более</label></div>');
        break;
        case '3':
        jQuery('#chfield').html('<label class="label3">Тип недвижимости:</label><div class="spad"><select name="srch_subtype" class="new" id="my_type"><option value="41">офисное помещение</option><option value="42">склад</option><option value="43">производственное помещение</option><option value="44">торговое помещение</option><option value="45">помещение свободного назначения</option><option value="46">помещение для оказания услуг</option><option value="47">земельный участок</option><option value="48">банковское помещение</option><option value="49">инвестпроект (готовый бизнес)</option><option value="50">помещение для сферы развлечений</option><option value="51">помещения под заведения общепита</option><option value="52">гараж/паркинг</option></select></div>');
    break;
        case '4':
        jQuery('#chfield').html('<label class="label3">Тип недвижимости:</label><div class="spad"><select name="srch_subtype" class="new"><option value="41">офисное помещение</option><option value="42">склад</option><option value="43">производственное помещение</option><option value="44">торговое помещение</option><option value="45">помещение свободного назначения</option><option value="46">помещение для оказания услуг</option><option value="47">земельный участок</option><option value="48">банковское помещение</option><option value="49">инвестпроект (готовый бизнес)</option><option value="50">помещение для сферы развлечений</option><option value="51">помещения под заведения общепита</option><option value="52">гараж/паркинг</option></select></div>');
        break;
        case '5':
        jQuery('#chfield').html('<label class="label3">Тип загородной недвижимости:</label><div class="spad"><select name="srch_subtype" class="new"><option value="12,22,31">дом</option><option value="12,23,32">коттедж</option><option value="14,24,33,47">земельный участок</option></select></div>');
        break;
        case '6':
        jQuery('#chfield').html('<label class="label3">Тип загородной недвижимости:</label><div class="spad"><select name="srch_subtype" class="new"><option value="12,22,31">дом</option><option value="12,23,32">коттедж</option><option value="14,24,33,47">земельный участок</option></select></div>');
        break;
        };
});
```

val srch_optype нормально реагирует - при разном значении - разное поле активно, а вот дальше не работает...

Comment: А зачем вообще создавать динамически поля? Формируйте страницу с нужными значениями сразу на сервере в зависимости от переданных параметров.

Comment: Доступов к серверу не дают, надо кастылить js :( так-бы на php можно было обработать - не спорю.

Comment: я не нашел знака  вопроса. расскажите больше, что именно не работает, что должно ? итд.

Comment: при запросе с get пармаетрами в URL - в форме вверху select, checkbox должен быть selected и checked соответствующие пункты формы.Не понятно как сделать...